# Why can a question have both a tag and its synonym simultaneously?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

This is probably answered somewhere, so apologies for my weak search-fu...

Why can a question have two tags that are synonyms? Shouldn't the synonym instead appear as its "parent" tag?

For instance in this question [Calculus used by Gauss to find Ceres' position?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/89380/calculus-used-by-gauss-to-find-ceres-position), [astronomy] and [observational-astronomy] both appear, even though [observational-astronomy] is a synonym of [astronomy].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrary to merging of tags, the creation of synonyms does not alter posts retroactively. If a question is edited after the synonym was created, the tags of the question will conform with the new synonym rules.